# Is there any way to create a Halcon Image (HImage) from an URI in C#?

Tags: c#, image, halcon

I am trying to create a `HSmartWindowControlWPF` and to set it's `HalconWindow` property.
It seems like a String does not work if the Image is not in the same directory. 
So I would like to create a `HImage` from a Uri in some way like this:

```
//create URI
Uri imagePath = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Mabri.Module.P83;Component/Images/HybridPACK_Drive_kLmL.png");

//create HImage
HImage image_kLmL = new HImage(imagePath);

//display Image
DetailImage.HalconWindow.DispImage(image_kLmL);
```

Any ideas are appreciated.